# How to change language direction from left to right in arcgis viewer for flex in layer list widget?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer, flash-builder

I have created my web map app using ArcGIS Viewer for Flex and want to change the direction of layer names in the layer list to the Arabic language direction (i.e. right to left; as below)

[my web mapp app http://imageshack.com/a/img822/3144/huod.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img822/3144/huod.png)

Comment: i just want to align "layer list, and layer Query"  from left to right.

Comment: i have read help arcgis viewr for flex in this link http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#//01m30000002r000000, but i cant how to start to make custom align text .